# Can I filter on deadlines in Trello?

Tags: trello

Is there a possibility to filter on deadline or only on deadlined cards?

We have deadlined cards and other cards without deadline.
As a team lead, I would like to see all deadlined cards, so I can change priority if needed.

Answer (score 5):

Using the Trello API, François de Metz created a third party web application called trello-calendar which shows all of your cards with deadlines on a calendar.
He runs it as a hosted app at https://trellocalendar-francois2metz.dotcloud.com/, but the source is also available on [github](https://github.com/francois2metz/trello-calendar).

If you are worried about using a third party trello app with your data, the developer has this to say about security on his site:

> Security No data are stored on our server.
>
> We ask for both read and write permissions. The write permission is to
> be able to update due date on cards.

Although this is not exactly native functionality, it may get the job done for you in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no functionality for this at this time. You could possible use a tag, label or particular person assigned to a card with a due date and filter by that as a work around.